# How to make modeling chocolate shiny?

Tags: chocolate, texture, presentation

I have modeling chocolate panels I am using for a cake. They have a very soft shine from being smooth, but I was hoping to bring them to a higher shine. I had wanted to make them out of tempered chocolate but the shape made it problematic. I've tried lightly buffing with my hand, but that is not doing enough. Can I use perhaps a warm, damp cloth or glaze with a mix of 1:1 corn syrup:alcohol? Would that make them tacky?

Comment: Can you form the structural body of whatever you are making from the modelling chocolate, then paint on true tempered chocolate for the appearance?

Comment: That was my current plan, although I may have to scrap the idea entirely as it's still not holding up. But thank you.

Comment: Is the problem that the tempered chocolate in the panels un-tempers in the molds?

Comment: How does this question differ from [this thread](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/18071/is-there-a-way-to-add-shine-to-a-chocolate-coating-after-it-has-hardened)? Is there a way to add shine to a chocolate coating after it has hardened?

Comment: I'd like to say that sanding with a very fine material and then buffing the chocolate by hand with something edible that could serve as a replacement for wax would work. (Such as the turtle wax used in automotive work) I'd also suggest working with the chocolate very cold to reduce or eliminate melting, as that would severely marr the finish. The method for this would be something someone with a greater knowledge of modeling chocolate's properties would have to work out.

Answer (score 2):

I think adding a few drips of vegetable oil or honey could help! Always heard other people say that.

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding just a small amount (1/4-1/2 teaspoon per bag of chocolate) of Paraffin or gulf wax ( canning wax) to your chocolate as your tempering it. The result is a super shiny chocolate that re hardens like normal. It’s an old trick my grandmother taught me when making homemade candy and filigree cake pieces. It does not change the taste of the chocolate either. I have not attempted it with modeling chocolate but do not see why it would not work the same when it is the fat content in your chocolate that makes the chocolate hold up and shine. The wax also adds strength to chocolate yet a very smooth shiney texture. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You could brush the modeling chocolate with pearl luster dust or white sparkle dust to make them shinier.

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! Promotional links are fine in your profile, and acceptable in answers if and **only** if they directly answer the question. Posting "related" links is not allowed. I've removed the link from your answer; it's good information, but does not provide any additional information on the specific question being asked.

Comment: Additionally, this answer should probably expanded upon, especially considering that the author wanted a shine from his or her chocolate, rather than a sparkle.

Answer (score 0):

Tempered chocolate spends a bit of time as firm but pliable before it turns completely hard. You could try cutting and shaping the chocolate into panels during this time, then apply them to the cake after they finish hardening.

Answer (score 0):

I recall my mother adding a tablespoon of butter per pound of chocolate at the end of the tempering process but the shine would only last for one day

Answer (score -2):

An hairdryer could help.
The idea is to make the outermost layer of chocolate just melt. The way I use mine is I turn the dryer on low speed and medium heat, and move the air flow over the chocolates.  Keep the dryer moving or it may melt too much!  With my dryer it only takes a few passes to do the trick.
Let the chocolates re-cool and you will be all set.

Comment: This answer would be much better if you provide some information on how to employ these techniques, although I suspect they simply won't work.

Comment: I also doubt that this would work. Tempering is actually what gives chocolate its shine; melting it with a hair dryer would most likely remove the temper, making it *less* shiny and also less stable.