# How can you Shine old Chocolate

Tags: chocolate

I have little hollow balls of old chocolate that I want to fill with ganache and seal. I want to keep the shape, how I can shine these?

I tried a heat gum and it looked fabulous till it dried and went dusty grey, every info I have found says to melt and redo.

How do you shine old chocolate without melting it?

Comment: is melting it and reshaping it an option, or do you want to do something while it stays solid?

Comment: Welcome to the site. This could be expanded into a great question, but we need a lot more details. For a start, what did you get when you googled this question, and how is it different from what you're looking for?

Comment: I don't. I just use it/eat it, and don't worry about *shiny!*

Comment: Every  info I have found says to melt and redo.  I wanted to keep the shape, they are little hollow balls that I can fill with ganache and seal.  I tried a heat gum and it looked fabulous till it dried and went dusty grey

Comment: I heavily edited your question putting in your info from the comment. Feel free to adjust as needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to add shine to a chocolate coating after it has hardened?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/18071/is-there-a-way-to-add-shine-to-a-chocolate-coating-after-it-has-hardened)